# Repos under project on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I'm not sure about the exact terminology but once I create a new project on VSTS, I want to have two folders/repositories under it i.e. "Master" and "Dev".

Dev will be the one I'll use on a daily basis and Master will contain the stable version that will be deployed to the staging site.

Two questions:

1. What is the right terminology for what I'm talking about? Are they
   repositories or folders or something else?
2. How do I create these two repositories/folders under my project?

Here's what I've done so far:
First I created my new project
[image]

I then navigated to the project and want to add those two repositories but not sure how to do it.
[image]

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create Dev branch for the repository.
Steps:

1. Create a Team project with Git Version control, by default, there is master branch
   [image]
2. Go to Code tab=>Branches
3. Click New branch button to create Dev branch from master
   [image]

On the other hand, you could create a git repository in the team project with Team Foundation Version Control, then create dev branch in this repository.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. My project uses Team Foundation Version Control and for some reason I do not see "branches" under Code in VSTS. Nevertheless, I was able to handle the creation of branches from Visual Studio -- though it was a workaround. I first created folders then converted folders to branches through Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio.